# What is the use of constructor() and what does it do?

Tags: kotlin, oop, constructor

I'm studying object oriented programming using Kotlin at the moment (I'm fairly new to it) and I came across this code:

```
class Human{
    var name:String = "Joe"

    var id:String = "123.123.123-12"    

    constructor()

    fun humanInfo() = "$name and $id"
}

fun main() {
    val joe = Human()

    println(joe.humanInfo())
}
```

I found out that there are primary and secondary constructors in Kotlin, but I didn't really understand what they are and what they do. What is the use of constructor() function here? And is it a primary constructor?

Comment: Have you read the docs? See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors

Comment: Yeah that ^ The primary constructor is where any parameters used in *constructing an instance of the class* go. You usually don't write the word `constructor`, just ``class MyClass(coolParam: String) {}``. If there are no parameters, you can drop the parentheses (you need them when calling the constructor though, `val thing = MyClass()`. Secondary constructors are for when you want to provide different ways to construct a `MyClass` using different parameters, but they always need to call the primary constructor internally. You can mostly just use default values in the primary instead

Comment: @lukas.j yes, they helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks for the explanation, I got it now :)